# Efectos al micrófono en web

Tags: javascript, html5

¿Cómo puedo conseguir poner un efecto/filtro al micrófono en HTML5? Lo que quiero conseguir es como esto:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/testdrive/demos/microphone/

Es decir, que escuche el propio efecto en directo. Me gustaría conseguirlo en HTML5, usando cualquier librería JS si es necesario

Comment: la página que indicas no existe amigo

Comment: @PabloAlcantar si que existe, pero por lo que se ve hoy están teniendo problemas con el servidor porque a veces deja y otras veces no. A primera hora funcionaba muy bien. Espero que vuelva a funcionar.

Comment: @PabloAlcantar ya funciona

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esos efectos no son propios de la API de WebAudio. De hecho, lo que hace ese demo es obtener por `AJAX` archivos `wav` para combinarlos con el audio tomado del micrófono.

Los filtros que te provee la interface [BiquadFilterNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/BiquadFilterNode) son los siguientes:

- Low pass
- Band pass
- High pass
- All pass
- Low shelf
- High shelf
- Peaking
- Notch

Éstos son los efectos con los que puedes jugar. Ésta interface también tiene las propiedades:

- `Q`: indica la calidad del audio `[0.001 - 1000]`
- `frequency`: la frecuencia en `Mhz`
- `type`: tipo de filtro

#### Ejemplo

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
  .then(stream => {
    let audio = document.getElementById('stream');
    let context = new AudioContext();
    // necesario para Firefox. Si no añadimos el stream
    // al objeto window, el microfono se detendrá pasados
    // unos segundos
    window.source = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
    let destination = context.createMediaStreamDestination();
    let filter = context.createBiquadFilter();
    filter.type = 'highshelf';
    filter.gain.value = 25;
    filter.frequency.value = 60;
    filter.Q.value = 50;
    source.connect(filter);
    filter.connect(destination);
    audio.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(destination.stream);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
    let output = document.getElementById('output');
    output.textContent = error.name;
  });
```

El método `getUserMedia` recibe un objeto que nosotros le pasamos para indicar qué queremos transmitir, si `audio` o `video` o ambos. Este método nos devolverá una promesa con el `stream` que se está capturando. A partir de aquí ya puedes manipularlo.

Por ejemplo, en el ejemplo de arriba he creado un `stream` de mi micrófono, del cual creo un `MediaStream` origen y destino por medio de `AudioContext` y también un filtro con algunos valores por defecto.

Para que se aplique el filtro, debemos hacer que la **fuente** se conecte al **filtro** y éste al **destino**. Una vez hecho ésto, tenemos en el destino el audio con el filtro aplicado. Para probarlo, basta convertirlo a `BLOB` y añadirlo a una etiqueta `audio`, como hago en la última línea.

#### Demostración

[image]

Puedes ver la demo en vivo [aquí](https://codepen.io/mitsug/full/ZpvgEq/).

---

Si mezclar las propiedades de `BiquadFilterNode` no te satisface, puedes usar la librería [Tuna](https://github.com/Theodeus/tuna), la cual te provee de varios efectos. Es en realidad un **decorador** para `AudioContext`.

Por ejemplo:

```
let tuna = new Tuna(context);
// necesario para Firefox. Si no añadimos el stream
// al objeto window, el microfono se detendrá pasados
// unos segundos
window.source = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
let destination = context.createMediaStreamDestination();

var effect = new tuna.Cabinet({
  makeupGain: 1, //0 to 20
  impulsePath: "telephone.wav", // tu impulsador de audio
  bypass: 0
});

source.connect(effect);
effect.connect(destination);
audio.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(destination.stream);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, tu respuesta me ha sido muy útil